# Where does Spring stores strings loaded from *.properties files?

Tags: java, spring, static

I have this two files:

**application.properties**

```
// ... stuffs ...
spring.profiles.active=some_id
```

**application-some_id.properties**

```
// ... stuffs ...
some.string=value
```

I want to get the value of the property "some.string" from my java code like this:

**Utility.java**

```
public final class Utility {

   public final static String SOME_STRING_VALUE = <Something>.getProperty("some.string");

   private Utility() {
   }

}
```

What should I write instead of `<Something>`? I know that working with spring I should use spring stuffs like @Value, @Component, etc ... and 99% of the project is like that. I'd like to have just this exception.

Comment: why not just use Spring's @Value annotation?

Comment: @Stultuske in my code (the provided example is a very short poc) i'd like to do that inside a static {} field.

Comment: this is worth a try https://mkyong.com/java/java-properties-file-examples/

Answer (score 0):

Try using the Environment API :

```
@Autowired
private Environment env;
.
.
env.getProperty("some.string");
```

Update : 
To be able to use in a static context you can try using lazy instantiation like follow (but in this case you should remove `final` accessor) :

```
final class Utility {

    @Autowired
    private Environment env;

    private static String SOME_STRING_VALUE;

    public static String getStringValue() {
        if (SOME_STRING_VALUE == null) {
            SOME_STRING_VALUE = env.getProperty("some.string");
        }
            return SOME_STRING_VALUE;
        }

    private Utility() {}

}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: To do that I would need to remove "static". Is there a way to manually create my Environment env object without using @Autowired?

Comment: @B.M. in order to do that, he would have to use spring. If he did that, he could just use @Value("")